# Matching between two groups of points in 3D space in R

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor

I have an unsorted group of N blue points and M red points in 3D space, where M<=N (each point is represented by X,Y,Z coordinates). Is there an "off the shelf" algorithm in R that can find for each red point the closest blue point?
The algorithm needs to minimize the sum of squares of euclidean distances between the M matched pairs, subject the constrain that the mapping is one to one, meaning that each blue point is mapped to no more than one red point. Notice that since M<=N, there will be some blue points without a match.

Comment: can you add some test data.

Comment: If you "find for each red point the closest blue point", then some blue point may be attached to more than one red point.  Is it what you want?

Comment: Look into bipartite graph matching

Comment: @user31264 - notice that the mapping should be one to one, meaning that each blue point can be attached to only one red point or no red point at all (since there are less red points than blue points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems what you need is close to the [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/assignment_problem), solved by [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) .  You should (1) reformulate this as an assignment problem and (2) check whether it is implemented in R (google for assignment problem R or Hungarian algorithm R, etc.)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Hungarian method is implemented in R by  clue::solve_LSAP()